# Mis-statement of First Principle of Mathematical Induction?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Maybe my problem is the English, but I cannot see why Gallian’s statement of the First Principle of Mathematical Induction is true.  In the 7th edition of Contemporary Abstract Algebra (p13) he states:

> Let $S$ be a set of integers containing $a$.  Suppose $S$ has the property that whenever some integer $n$ greater than or equal to $a$ belongs to $S$, then the integer $n+1$ also belongs to $S$. Then $S$ contains every integer greater than or equal to $a$.

Let $S=\{1,5,7,12,13,14,15,...\}$ and let $a=7$. The integers $(n)$ will be the integers $12$ and above. This set $S$ meets the criterion since the inclusion of every such $n$ implies $n+1$ is also in $S$.  But clearly $S$ does not contain every integer greater than or equal to $a$.

Comment: 7 belongs to $S$ but $8$ doesn't, so your $S$ doesn't meet the condition

Comment: What if $n=7{}$?

Comment: If $a=7$, the criterion says we must have $8\in S$, which isn't so.

Comment: He says for SOME n greater than a.  He does not say for EVERY n greater than a. So the condition is met.

Comment: In the statement of the induction principle, you chose  $a=7$ in the first sentence, but  $a=12$ in the second sentence. But the intent is that they both denote the same element $a\in S$ so you can't do that. The intent is that $\,n= a\,$ is the *base case* of the induction (generalizing the usual base case  $\,a=0)\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

I think you have overlooked the fact that if $a = 7,$ then $7$ is an integer greater than or equal to $a.$

If $a = 7$ and if $S$ had the property that whenever some integer $n$ greater than or equal to $a$ belongs to $S$, then the integer $n+1$ also belongs to $S$,
we could set $n = 7$, and then the fact that $n \geq a$ and $n \in S$
would imply that $n + 1 = 8$ also belonged to $S.$

Since $8$ is not in $S$, $S$ does not have the property that the principle of induction requires.

The whole point of the principle of induction is that it applies to all integers $n$ that are greater than or equal to $a$, including $a$ itself.
So first you set $n = a$ and therefore $n+1 = a+1$ must be in the set.
Then you set $n = a+1$ and therefore $n+1 = a+2$ must be in the set.
And so forth ad infinitum.

Comment: Maybe the problem is language, not math.  He says you need SOME integer greater than a that meets the condition.  In S, there is some such integer, and it is 12.

Comment: You say “ALL integers greater than or equal to a”.  But he says “SOME integer greater or equal to a”.

Comment: He doesn't just say "*some* integer." He says "*whenever* some integer $n$ ... ." That means you don't get to just pick one $n$. The statement has to be true *whenever* $n \geq a.$ In plain English, if the law says, "whenever you rob a bank you will go to jail," you don't get to say that if you rob a bank on June 5 you go to jail but any other day is OK; it means *every day* is a day you will go to jail if you rob the bank then.

Comment: So yes, the problem is the language. You have to learn to read mathematical English. "Whenever some integer $n$ has this property then ..." means the same thing as, "For every integer $n$ that has this property ... ." It's completely different from what we mean when we say, "*There exists* some integer $n$ such that ... ."

Answer (score 1):

The definition is not wrong. The thing you are missing is that if $S$ is our set containing $a$, the condition is that for **every** $n\geq a$, if $n \in S$ then $n+1\in S$. So in your example while it is true that for **some** $n \geq a$, (particularly $n\geq 12$), it is not true that every integer $\geq a$ satisfies the property. For example since $a=7$ and $n=7\geq 7$, the fact that $7 \in S$ should imply that $8\in S$ but this is clearly not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion seems to be the fact that you think you can choose **both** $a$ and the starting point for $n$ independently. (you chose $a=7$ but your $n$ starts at 12$).

But the following sais that you have to check for all $n$'s **starting at $n=a$**

```
"whenever some integer $n$ greater than or equal to $a$ belongs to S, then the integer n+1 also belongs to S."
```

Comment: Right, but that’s not what he says.

Comment: @PossumP " and let a=7. The integers (n) will be the integers 12 and above. "...<--- What is he saying here?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is meant to be read as $$\forall S\subseteq \Bbb Z, ((a\in S\land \forall n\ge a, (n\in S\Rightarrow n+1\in S))\Rightarrow (\forall m\ge a, m\in S))$$

Id est, that if $S$ is a subset of $\Bbb Z$ containing $a$ and such that, for all $n\ge a$, if $n\in S$ then $n+1\in S$, then $S$ contains all the integers greater or equal to $a$. It's a cumbersome statement to make in natural language, all the more if you try to squeeze it inside a single sentence. In my opinion the statement you are quoting, as an English sentence, is rather clumsy and imprecise, but I think that even there you could try and grasp where the quantifiers are supposed to be.